# How to generate dsym files near the executable, not outside the bundle, preferably without a post install script?

Tags: xcode, macos, llvm, dsym, dsymutil

I'm using LLVM Clang with Xcode and address sanitiser is not creating file:line report. I read the documentation and it says to run `dsymutil` on the binary before launching the app.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#symbolizing-the-reports

I can achieve that by adding a run script build phase but it is clunky. To do the same with unix-makefiles I figured an `install(SCRIPT <script.cmake>)` would be better.

Is there a way to avoid all this and have Xcode run `dsymutil` as part of the build process, probably by a build setting that I don't know about ?

I've tried setting debugging information format to dwarf with dsym, but llvm-symbolizer doesn't use it. I guess that the difference is that dsymutil creates the .dsym file near the executable, *inside* the bundle :`MyExec.dsym`. While Xcode creates it *outside* the bundle: `MyExec.app.dsym`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Build Settings in Xcode, change the debug format from "DWARF" to "DWARF with dSYM".

Comment: That creates the dsym file, but I guess at the wrong place. Please see the edited question. llvm-symbolizer is not seeing the dsym file if it is away from the binary, near the bundle.